# Google oAuth breaks when using multiple gunicorn workers

Tags: python, nginx, flask, web, gunicorn

When I try to login to my website using Google, I will get this error (sometimes).
"oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response."

The error happens at this if statement:

```
@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)

    if not session["state"] == request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)  # State does not match!
```

What I think is happening is that multiple workers create different session tokens or something like that. Im not to familiar with web stuff.

I tried changing the amount of workers to 1 and the site works fine. Which is what proves my theory of whats wrong. I just dont know how to fix it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the if statement I've learned.